# Asymmetrical details in symmetrical object

Tags: mirror-modifier

I have a symmetrical object with the mirror modifier and I want to add asymmetrical details to it. Is this possible without applying the mirror modifier?

Comment: no this is not possible (maybe with Geonodes though), but maybe show your case, there may be some solutions

Comment: Thank you. I want to create a car that is not symmetrical in all areas.

Comment: in that case create several object, at the end apply the modifiers and join all the objects

Comment: Good idea. Thank you!